# How to call RESTFul WCF service with Forms authentication

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, wif, restful-authentication

**Assumptions:**

Client is a Web application (ASP.NET) configured for STS Passive Issue
Server is a MVC Application with 2 services (1. Issues a token and other gets metadata)
Server on the other hand configured for Forms authentication and should redirect to Login page if unauthenticated access is made.

**Workflow:**

1. end user tries to load client.
2. It contact the STS by redirecting to the STS server.
3. The server is configured with Forms authentication with a redirect URL.

But Server does not redirect to login page. instead it allows to call the Issue end point.

I tried to restrict via authorization tag in web.config. Also, i tried location tag to set authorization explicitly. But it still allows the call.

i referred many blogs

[How to: Enable the WCF Authentication Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398990.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396,)

[How to: Customize User Login When Using the WCF Authentication Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398862(v=vs.100).aspx,"MSDN")

But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to achieve with ADFS. Use the following steps if ADFS is your STS:

1. Navigate to the folder where ADFS web application is located (normally C:\inetpub\adfs\ls)

   2. Make a copy of the current web.config for safety
   3. Open web.config in notepad
   4. Locate
   5. In  , change the order of authentication to assure that it lists Forms Authentication first
   6. The order must look like this:

   ```
   <add name="Forms" page="FormsSignIn.aspx" />       

   <add name="Integrated" page="auth/integrated/" />

   <add name="TlsClient" page="auth/sslclient/" />

   <add name="Basic" page="auth/basic/" />
   ```

   7. Save the changes (you do not need to restart ADFS)
   8. Navigate to your application and click on Login. Instead of sending the login request to ADFS, a page containing a login dialog will pop up. Please enter your credential and click ok. Then, you will get the same result as above.

Reference articles:

[Claims Aware MVC4 App using WIF Identity and Access tool in .Net 4.5 Part I](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2013/10/01/claims-aware-mvc4-app-using-wif-identity-and-access-tool-in-net-4-5.aspx)

[Claims Aware MVC4 App using WIF Identity and Access tool in .Net 4.5 Part II](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2013/10/09/claims-aware-mvc4-app-using-wif-identity-and-access-tool-in-net-4-5-part-ii.aspx)